# Subversion, How to setup test server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a client that gave me the SVN login credentials to his repository.

Though, he is very busy to deploy everytime I commit. How can I setup a test site for my own? Any idea guys?

TIA

---

well my client has an existing website and they want me to edit it, they give me access to the SVN, however once you commit the changes it is not updating the existing website, I already have the URL for the SVN username and password, what I want to do is everytime I commit I can test the changes. I never used SVN before

Comment: What do you mean by "he is very busy to deploy"? By "setup a test site", do you mean create your own repository or check out a working copy?

Comment: everytime I commit something the changes i did is not updating to the website, so I think that maybe it wasn't deployed yet. Sorry this is the first time that I used SVN and I really want to know everything about it

Comment: Can you commit to the Subversion repository? Do you want to deploy your code on some server? If so, this really isn't a Subversion question. If you want to deploy to a test website, you'll need to create a test website and copy your code into there. For that, we need more information. What type of website is it? Is there a database involved? Can you use an existing database?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about deploying and testing.  This is not what SVN is for.  You need to set up a testing environment for whatever it is that you are developing in, such as a LAMP stack or Tomcat or a Xbox.

Answer (score 0):

Right CLick -> Tortoise SVN -> Create Repository Here.

Use `Right CLick -> Tortoise SVN -> Repo Browser` to get the URL. It will be something like: `file:///C:/path/to/repo`